# logfile endpoint does not find log path

Tags: spring-boot-actuator

We have a Log4j2.xml which configures a RollingFileAppender. Now I want to expose these logs with the `logfile` actuator endpoint.

If I specify logging.file in the application.yml like this

```
logging:
   file: target/logs/mylog.log
```

everything is fine.
However, this does not work (invoking the logfile-endpoint results in a 404):

```
logging:
   path: /target/logs
```

How can I get the logfile endpoint to show the mylog-1.log, mylog-2.log,... files?

Comment: in the first example you use a relative file path target/logs in the second example you use an absolute path /target/logs

Comment: I also tried `target/logs`or `target/logs/`with the same result.